# Using out variable from previuos step in if condition

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have a question about using the variable from the previous step in the if condition.
I have a first step which fill some variable, and I want that the second step runs the different code based on the variable from step 1. To test the solution I wrote the next code:

```
trigger: none
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Out Server
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ServerName]SomeServer"
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Test Server
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      ${{ if ne(variables.ServerName, '') }}:
        script: Write-Output "Server is $(ServerName)"                    
      ${{ else }}:
        script: Write-Output "Server is empty. '$(ServerName)' "
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Test Server 2
    condition: and(succeeded(),ne(variables['ServerName'], '')) 
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: Write-Output "Server is $(ServerName)"
```

The weird thing the the "Test Server" task goes by the way when `variables.ServerName` is empty and provides the next: Server is empty. 'SomeServer' 
The "Test Server 2" step works as it should.

Based on what I found in the documentation [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages) and  [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops): Using of variables in `if` condition is possible only in cases when the variable known before the job start. I guess that `if` is  calculated at the begging of the job, unlike `condition` calculates at the beginning of each step.
Deas anyone know how to use the variable from the previous step in `if` statement?

Server is empty. 'SomeServer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables defined at runtime in compile-time conditionals. `${{}}` syntax is evaluated at template compilation time, which is *before* the pipeline starts running.

In your case, you're running a PowerShell script. So just map the variable in as an environment variable (via an `env:` block) and write the conditional logic in PowerShell.

The answer to your core question, "*Deas anyone know how to use the variable from the previous step in if statement?*" is simply and unfortunately: **You can't.**